# How to get only the used pip packages?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I'm aware of `pip freeze` and `pip list`, but how do I output the packages used in a specific python file to a `requiremants.txt` file?

Is there an option to specify a file?

Comment: If you’re looking to write the import dependencies of a specific py project to a `requirements.txt` file; `pipreqs` will do the job.

Comment: With good unittest coverage you could start with an empty virtualenv and run pip install until every import error went away.  There are more advanced ways to do this stuff, but that’s a low complexity quick way to do it once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No there is not. `pip freeze` doesn't check any of the files in your project, it simply checks the installed packages in your Python environment.

You can check all of the options that `pip freeze` takes here: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_freeze/

The similar `pip list` command does not offer such an option either: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_list/

You could try `pipreqs` though, it might suit your use case: https://github.com/bndr/pipreqs

Answer (score 2):

Pip freeze usually creates a packages list of the whole environment.
That is why pipreqs is the recommended option for only these packages used in your project.

```
pip install pipreqs

cd /to/your/python/project

pipreqs . # creates a requirements.txt from the used packages in an environment.
```